# Questions regarding the definitions of Function Limits and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently teaching myself mathematical analysis, and the books I am using are "mathematical analysis by Elias Zakon, please refer to [http://www.trillia.com/dA/zakon-analysisI-a4-two.pdf"](http://www.trillia.com/dA/zakon-analysisI-a4-two.pdf%22). I find it confusing when the author says in Chapter 4 (page 150, bottom of this page, footnotes 3), "**Because of this, some authors restrict Definition 2 to the case where A clusters at p. However, this has its disadvantages (e.g., Corollary 2 fails)**."

Note 1: In chapter 4, the author introduces the definitions of *continuous functions* and "function limit" and then this concerned footnote is posed. Refer to [continuous functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBP6F.png) and [function limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd0EB.png).

Note 2: "The referred Corollary 2 says: "f is continuous at p (**p ∈ Dom f** ) if and only if f(x) approaches f(p) as x approaches p." See [related to Corollary 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP85x.png)

I would like to get an answer to this. Specifically, why is it not possible to restrict "A clusters at p"? Also, why does Corollary 2 above not hold when this requirement is added?

Comment: What is "definition 2" and what is "A"?

Comment: As I see after quick view at book, definition of continuation does not required clustering and if one request clustering only for limit definition, then you cannot use limit and continuity together:  the limit may not exist, but continuity holds.

Comment: Please type relevant portions of the book instead of expecting us to have a copy of the book.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your kind reminder. The hyperlink to the book I used has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be writing from the copy Zakon E. - Mathematical analysis, 1-(2004)(btw at moment I am writing this answer the above link to book in question is dead). For the sake of accuracy and for the readers of this answer, I will repeat some points from the book.

On page $149$, Definition $1$ is started with that function $f$ is said to be continuous in point $p$, when point $p$ is in domain of $f$: $p\in A=D_f$ and then the sentence $(1)$ is formulated:

$$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)\Big(\forall x\in G_{p}(\delta)\cap A\Big)\Big(f(x)\in G_{f(p)}(\varepsilon)\Big)\quad (1)$$
So, continuity is defined only at  points $p\in A$.

But immediately after the definition of continuity comes the notion of discontinuity based only on the negation of proposition (1) i.e.  set of discontinuity points  includes points, that do not belong to the domain of  $f$. Once again, let me emphasize that the author is not talking about continuity outside the domain of definition, but only about discontinuity. Therefore, since the main question is about the Corollary 2 , then in the future I will write only about the point $p\in A$.

It's important, that in definition of continuity we have no restrictions on the point $p$ and its neighborhood $G_p(\delta)$.

Next  (page $150$, Definition $2$) comes the definition of the limit, but now we have a neighborhood of a different type, the so-called deleted neighborhood $G_{\neg p}(\delta)$, in relation to which the sentence $(2)$ is formulated:

$$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)\Big(\forall x\in G_{\neg p}(\delta)\cap A\Big)\Big(f(x)\in G_{q}(\varepsilon)\Big)\quad (2)$$

Again no restriction on $p$ in Definition $2$. But this gives, that if $p$ is  so-called [isolated point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point), i.e. $\exists\delta > 0,G_{\neg p}(\delta)\cap A =\emptyset $, then limit always exists for any $q$ and is not unique.

To get rid of this inconvenience, the author suggests to consider additionally  to Definition $2$, instead of any $p$ point, the so-called [limit  point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point) (accumullation point,clustering point) i.e. $A$ clusters at $p$. So, now, as we have deleted neighborhoods, then in any such neighborhood exists at least one point from $A$ **different** from $p$. This gives uniqueness of limit, if it exists.

And now we have come to the answer to the main question: why is it not fulfilled Corollary $2$ if we add  constraint "$A$ clusters at $p$" to Definition $2$?

The fact is that the definition of continuity does not impose a restriction on a point $p$. It can be isolated point and the function at such a point is automatically continuous. But we do not have the concept of the limit of a function at an isolated point, as we added restriction about clustering, so, we cannot formulate Corollary $2$.

p.s.

Corollary $2$. $f$ is continuous at $p\in D_f$ iif $f(x)\to f(p)$ as $x\to p$.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions！

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Feel free to ask more if/when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if $p$ is not a member of $A$. then $f(p)$ is undefined.